# How can I add fields to drupal's comments form?

Tags: drupal

I use drupal6 as my blog and don't want to require to register for making comments to my posts. However, I would like to require them to enter a name, an e-mail and a website (optional) as it is usual in blogs.

Is there any module for drupal that can do this? Can I use the core module for comments and the cck? What options do I have, and how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment module in drupal core can do the required functionality by itself.

It can be enabled by going to

```
Administer->content-type
```

then edit the node-type for which the contact info for anonymous users should be required and go to comment settings.

There is an option to disable, make it optional, or required it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://drupalmodules.com/module/node-comments i am not sure if you can make the field required or not but that modules allows you to have custom fields.

Or if you prefer you can alter the code yourself and create the fields any way you want it.

[Simply add a field to comments](http://drupal.org/node/399410)

You should get a lot more answer with this question at http://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. Somehow this question does not fit any site perfectly, since it is not really a programming or development question either.

Comment: It is actually a php CMS question and fits Stackoverflow very much :) hence why you might actually get more answers there.

Comment: +1 for the link to drupalmodules. I found something that helped with additional things there.

Comment: So in other words this actually solves your problem and needs. GL